# SSRS Near Real Time Report Refresh

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Afternoon all.

I have built a near real time reporting solution for use in our call centre to track activity. The idea is to have this on a big screens so all staff can see the current days progress against targets.

The report is built in SSRS and currently is set to refresh every 90 seconds. each of the 3 queries that pull the data are sub 1 second queries but the report itself is taking up to 3 seconds to re-load which is very visible thanks to the loading screen which flashes up.

What I would like to know is if there is a way of surpressing that loading screen (so that the numbers just change) or if there is a way to speed up the report that I have not yet thought of. I think the problem lies within the render time for the report but I am not certain.

Any help greatly received.

Comment: What are you hosting your SSRS report in? A report viewer control in a webpage or windows forms app? If so you could do something funky like start the report refresh up on a hidden screen, and then swap out the screens after it has had enough time

Comment: The SSRS report is just running in webpage.

Comment: If you check the execution logs in the report server database you'll be able to see whats taking the time. As far as I know though, there is no way to do what you ask assuming you are just viewing the report from a browser pointing to http://myServerName/Reports

Comment: Thanks Alan, The largest element of the run is the Render time which is on average 4 times the combined time for Data Retrieval and Processing time. I'm not sure how I can speed up the render time. Any suggestions welcome. Ta

Comment: How many rows of data is the report fetching, and can it be summarised in SQL rather than sending it raw to the report? SSRS isn't particularly great at working with any volume of data quickly (even as few as 100s of rows, say). If you can filter and summarise as much as you can in the initial query it's almost always MUCH more effiecnt to do so.

Comment: Thanks Jerb, That sadly not an option due to the data requirements. I've actually removed the toolbar for this report which seems to have sped the whole solution up considerably. It means giving each team parameterised links for the web browser but that's not a major problem.

Comment: This use case seems more suited to a PowerBI dashboard with streaming data.